# Is it possible make a back-end for WordPress with WordPress?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

Here's what my boss wants me to do on our website: display how often one of our other websites has been 'Up and Running' by percentage of time per month. I told him I would need to make an AWS instance that pings that other website and stores the historic data (and sends it to our WordPress site when requested). But he says it is possible to do all of this through WordPress. Who is right? Are there plug-ins for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just tell him to sign up to uptimerobot.com, more accurate than most with SMS, Email and Push alerts to downtime.

Comment: But we want the data to be displayed at our website.

Comment: You can use uptimerobots "status" page,  basically a CNAME display so you can have the monitoring and status displayed on a subdomain like  status.yourdomain.com

Comment: It would look similar to this : https://status.uptimerobot.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help. But we want to use the data and put it into our custom calendar with JavaScript.

Comment: Use their API to develop your own data capture then,  there really is no need to reinvent the wheel that is likely to be less reliable when you can pull all the data you need.  The status page using Cname was a suggestion,  there is alot more you can do with their API : http://blog.uptimerobot.com/apiv2-is-ready-to-use-apiv1-will-be-retired-on-1-june-2017/

Comment: https://uptimerobot.com/api  ,  you create custom reports and store the results in your own database for long term historical reporting

Comment: Huge help Randomer11!